# Moving labels on circle

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a circle that turns over, how can i put on him some labels that will turn with him also?
my point is that the circle and labels should be on same angel.

Answer (score 1):

Make the label a subview of the UIView you are using to present the circle. 
In IB just drag the label onto the the UIView you are using for the circle image or if you are not using IB just add the label to the circle like this:
`[circleUIView addSubview:theUILabel];`

Answer (score 0):

```
Download demo source code this url http://www.devedup.com/index.php/2010/03/03/iphone-animate-an-object-along-a-path/

Now changes into Canvas.m file's animateCicleAlongPath method.

Replace to image to label.

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    [label setText:@"test"];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    //Set the frame of the view - which is used to position it when we add it to our current UIView
    label.frame = CGRectMake(1, 1, 20, 20);
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self addSubview:label];
    [label.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"moveTheSquare"];
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i dont see here where it moves... I have a circle object that moves around, where exactly i add this code? its only showing the label without moving around